# using namespace in function implementation

Tags: c++, namespaces

In C++, could I use `using namespace std;` declaration in the function implementation files?

Comment: I don't really seem to understand your question... Could you give some more info?

Comment: Who nominated this for reopening?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By "function implementation files" do you mean the .h files or the .cpp files? (I would normally call .cpp files "implementation" files, while .h files are "interface" files.)

If you mean, .cpp files, then of course. That is where you normally see `using namespace std`. It means that all the code in this .cpp file has access to `std` without qualification.

If you mean .h files, then you *can*, but you shouldn't. If you include it in a .h file, it will automatically apply to any .cpp file which includes the .h file, which could be a lot of files. You generally don't want to be telling *other* modules which namespaces to import. It is best to put it in every .cpp file rather than in a common .h file.

Edit: User @lachy suggested an edit which I won't include verbatim, but they suggested I point out that `using namespace std` is usually considered bad practice, due to namespace pollution. They gave a link to a question on this topic: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Yes, I mean the cpp files. I use using namespace std in the main cpp file and "std::" in the function .cpp (not main functions) files, so I just curious about using namespace in the function cpp file.

Comment: @Sean: there are no special rules for the "main" .cpp file. There are only some rules about the `main` _function_ (can only `int` etcetera) but those rules do not have any effect on the other functions or classes that happen to be defined in the same file.

Answer (score 129):

Maybe you would like to know too that you can put `using namespace std;` within a function body as well, like below. This will restrict the scope of the `using namespace` statement.

```
void f() {
  using namespace std;
  cout << "Foo" << endl;
  //..
};

void g() {
  cout << "Bar" << endl; //ERROR: cout and endl are not declared in this scope.
};
```

This can be useful if you want to use a lot of elements of a namespace in the body of a function that is written in a header file (which you shouldn't per se, but sometimes it is OK or even almost necessary (e.g. templates)).

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming you mean something like this:

```
// Foo.h

void SayHello();
```

...

```
// Foo.cpp

#include "Foo.h"

using namespace std;

void SayHello()
{
    cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
}
```

If that is the case, then yes.  However, it's considered bad practice to use `using namespace std;` in larger projects.

Comment: I'd try to avoid using "using namespace" even in implementation files, if later you want to use a single translation unit you'll get name conflicts.

Answer (score 4):

if by "function implementation files" you mean the .C/.cpp etc. files, you can, however try to avoid. Instead inject what you need in only, for example if you need `<iostream>` for `std::cout`, `std::endl` etc. just inject these two in, `using std::cout;` and `using std::endl;`, now you can simply write `cout` and `endl`.